# Keyboard ignoring Alt-X

Tags: keyboard, windows-8.1

I got a new laptop (Toshiba S50-B-020, Windows 8.1) and the keyboard is 99.9% fine, except that it does nothing when I type Alt-Z, Alt-X or Alt-C.  The Alt key works with all other combinations that I tested, the Z, X and C keys work normally when not used with Alt.

I tried [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) to see if a program was intercepting those as Windows hotkeys, but it is not the case.  Also, I should mention that if I plug in an external keyboard, Alt-X does work correctly.

The laptop keyboard is some type of "international" keyboard with a few weird symbols on some keys, but it is basically just a normal US keyboard.  I played around with the Windows language and keyboard layouts, but it did not help.

I found the webpage for the drivers for my laptop, but it does not seem to have a driver for the keyboard.  In the device manager, the keyboard is listed as Standard PS/2 Keyboard.  I have the latest bios.

I followed one suggestion from [Toshiba](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Keyboards-Touchpads-Knowledge/What-can-I-do-if-my-keyboard-is-not-functioning-properly-in/ta-p/281633) and removed the keyboard from the device manager and rebooted, but it did not help.  Another solution is to re-install Windows, but that is a pain and I'm not sure if the keyboard ever worked correctly.  I cannot use a restore point since that was not activated.

I had posted this question earlier and it was marked as duplicate since it seemed I just asking how to find the active hotkeys.  I am also askingn for help on the Toshiba [forum](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Keyboards-Touchpads/Alt-X-not-working-on-laptop-S50-B-020/m-p/622385/highlight/false).

Comment: I'm wondering of Alt-X is not disabled on French and French Canadian machines.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a faulty keyboard to me, call Toshiba and arrange to have it tested/replaced, since you say it's "new", it's most likely still under warranty.  They may still make you reinstall Windows once before they'll accept that it's a hardware problem, so you might as well try that first.

If it's really too much of a "pain" to do that, then I'd suggest you pack it up and go pay a professional to do it for you.

Comment: I ran linux from a USB key.  It had the same issue with Alt-X, so it definitely is hardware related.